# Append multiple items to path in fish shell (equivalent to: +=)

Tags: shell, fish

For example [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) has a user define additional ruby paths via. the following:

RUBIES +=(
  /opt/jruby-1.7.0
  "$HOME/src/rubinius"
)

Is there a nice way to accomplish this in fish?

Answer (score 10):

All fish variables are arrays. So in theory this would be as simple as

```
set -x RUBIES $RUBIES /opt/jruby-1.7.0 "$HOME/src/rubinius"
```

Unfortunately fish won't automatically convert that array to a string of colon separated values when it exports the var. At the present time fish only does that for PATH and MANPATH.

You can do it like this:

```
set -x RUBIES "$RUBIES:/opt/jruby-1.7.0:$HOME/src/rubinius"
```

But that assumes RUBIES has already been set; otherwise you get a string with a leading colon which may, or may not, have special meaning for any software using the var. Dealing with that is straightforward:

```
if set -q RUBIES[1]
    set -x RUBIES "$RUBIES:/opt/jruby-1.7.0:$HOME/src/rubinius"
else
    set -x RUBIES "/opt/jruby-1.7.0:$HOME/src/rubinius"
end
```

Too, if you're using fish 2.3 (soon to be released) or a fish built from git head you can use the new "string" builtin to split and join the string on colons:

```
set rubies (string split ':' $RUBIES)
set rubies $rubies /opt/jruby-1.7.0 "$HOME/src/rubinius"
set -x RUBIES (string join ':' $rubies)
```

Comment: It's really ugly that you have to use 5 lines to do something you could do in one line of bash isn't it?